# Why does my new AMD GPU support only up to OpenCL 1.2?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, opencl

OpenCL 2.0 was released November 2013. Yet the laptop I bought in January 2017 has an AMD GPU that only supports up to OpenCL 1.2, despite the GPU being released in May 2015.

The laptop has these two GPUs:

- AMD Radeon R5 M330
- Intel HD Graphics 5500

The latter has OpenCL 2.0 support, but that's little consolation when I bought the laptop to develop OpenCL apps with the more powerful, discrete AMD GPU.

**Was I wrong in thinking that any GPU released even a few months after the release of a technology (like OpenCL), will support that technology?**

Answer (score 0):

The Radeon Rx 300 series actually includes 3 different generations of graphics processor from AMD.  As such support for technologies such as OpenCL is dependant on the hardware supporting the minimum feature set of the version of OpenCL.

- [GCN 1st gen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#first)
- [GCN 2nd gen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#second)
- [GCN 3rd gen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#third)

GCN 1st Gen appears to only support OpenCL 1.2 while generations 2 and above support OpenCL2.0.

In the [desktop range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_300_series#Desktop_products) all three of these generations are represented, with only the lowest performing cards using the 1st Gen architecture.

In the [mobile market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_300_series#Mobile_products) for the 300 series almost all but the high end R9 3xx processors are using the GCN 1st Gen architecture.  As a result most of the mobile market for this series, outside of ultra-high end gaming laptops, will only support OpenCL1.2 rather than 2.0.

It's a pity, but if you need specific features then you need to make sure they're there before purchasing.

Comment: Even the [4xx series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_400_series) has this problem of fragmented software support across the series with GCN 1st Gen being in attendance and limited to OpenCL 1.2. It stinks, but it appears that AMD either had a lot of leftover stock they were constantly rebranding, or they were milking the architecture for all it was worth. Even the 5xx claims a couple of GCN 1st Gen parts.